# How to disable audit reporting on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-8.1

On a multi-user Windows 8.1 development machine, there have been many slowdowns when accessing via RDP. In reviewing the event viewer, I noticed that there are many audits running in the security section, which seem excessive and unnecessary: every few seconds, dozens of events are generated:

[image]

I have tried changing the local security policy, but it seems to already be disabled:

[image]

So, how do I disable the auditing? Or should it be a concern?

Comment: This can be done by an `Administrator` domain user.

Comment: I right click and ran as administrator the local security policy (secpol.msc) as a local account Administrator. All accounts on this machine are local accounts.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the image closely, it appears that at least one of those audit entries were logging "an attempt to query the existence of a blank password for an account." Whenever somebody logs on (or UAC-elevates, if I remember correctly), one or more of these events are logged as the system checks to see if people have blank passwords; it wouldn't make much sense for the logon UI to prompt for a password if the user didn't have one.

These aren't a problem unless you have an insane amount of logons (or, perhaps, automated Run As invocations) happening all the time. But, since you asked how to get rid of them, here we go:

The Local Security Policy UI lies to you about certain audited activities. (There are actually several activities involved in each of those categories; it generalizes.) To see exactly what is audited, run `auditpol /get /category:*` at an administrative command prompt. To fully disable auditing, run `auditpol /clear`, then reboot.

You can back up and restore the audit policy (if you think somebody legitimately and purposefully set up a custom policy) using the `/backup` and `/restore` switches on `auditpol`, both of which require a `/file:"\path\to\file"` argument immediately following.

Read more about auditing [at TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn319078.aspx).